# "Pretty good" vs. "pretty bad"

Tags: american-english, slang

What is the difference between using "pretty bad" and "pretty good" in this kind of slang context? It seems to be more of an American English quirk.

> - Looks like you hurt your leg pretty bad
> - Looks like you hurt your leg pretty good

Comment: These sentences, the second one especially, reflect an inelegant use of English, in a register of uneducated street slang. A better way to say the same thing would simply be : 'It looks as if you hurt your leg badly'. It is not entirely wrong, when speaking in a higher register, to use *pretty* to mean *very*.

Comment: I couldn't call this slang with a straight face. This is perfectly fine spoken English, and the meaning is transparent to absolutely everyone. Slang [is](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slang) “very informal usage in vocabulary and idiom that is characteristically more metaphorical, playful, elliptical, vivid, and ephemeral than ordinary language”. Absolutely nothing in either phrase remotely fits that definition.

Comment: @RegDwigнt "This is perfectly fine spoken English" except both sentences use an adjective when an adverb should be used. ("Badly" instead of "bad") This mistake, however, is very common. (Unfortunately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from containing bad grammar, yes, the two sentences illustrate a quirk in at least AE. *Bad* and *good* mean pretty much the same thing in your exemplars. (A special case, or exception, involves the use of *bad* to **mean** *good*, as in, "That's a *bad* pair of kicks you wearin.'")

I'd summarize the slight differences between the two sentences as follows:

> - "pretty bad" implies/connotes the injury is severe. A person viewing the injury would likely wince when saying "that's pretty bad." Perhaps the (say) laceration is particularly deep and/or is bleeding profusely, or a broken bone is protruding from the skin (an "open, compound fracture"), or the injury simply "grosses out" the observer.
> - "pretty good" implies/connotes the injury is not minor, but possibly major. In a sense, "pretty good" is analogous to the exception I pointed out above. Instead of bad meaning good, here good means bad! In other words, in a twisted and ironic sort of way, the observer is complimenting the injured person on how "well" s/he injured the leg.

In conclusion, there is an element of irony in your second exemplar, which makes the sentence a little perverse, but generally acceptable and inoffensive. Moreover, by focusing on the "good" aspect of the injury, the observer diffuses or lessens the anxiety or fear the injured person might experience, better than the word *bad*!

Comment: Bad grammar? How so?

Comment: @curiousdannii: You know, "Winston tastes good LIKE [wrong] a cigarette should"! So, to begin with, change the "looks like" to "looks as though," and then change the "hurt your leg pretty bad" to "hurt your leg badly." As for the "pretty good," I suggest either "Looks as if you did a good job hurting your leg," or "Looks as though you hurt your leg pretty well." OK, so I'm a little persnickety, but I wouldn't bust someone's chops for speaking or writing either sentence (although I might attempt to bust your chops--just kidding). Don

Comment: I would say that the difference between "pretty bad" and "pretty good" here is what is being modified.  "You hurt your leg pretty bad" is modifying the leg - the leg is in a very bad state.  On the other hand "You hurt your leg pretty good" the pretty good is modifying the "hurt"...you have done an essentially complete job of injuring that leg.

Comment: @Oldcat: You have a point, and I do not disagree. Toe-may-toe/toe-mah-toe. Whether one gussies up expressions such as these or not, native speakers understand immediately what they mean. On the other hand, non-native speakers might question not only the grammar, but also the meaning. That's THEIR problem, though, isn't it. Don

Answer (score 2):

In the context given, *pretty* is used for emphasis.

The online dictionaries don't *quite* capture this use. See, for example:

> ... To a fair degree; moderately: a pretty good student. ...

-- [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pretty)